# What is this numerical approximation for definite integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, notation, approximation

I've recently been reading [a programming textbook](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-12.html#call_footnote_Temp_91) that I've seen recommended to undergraduates. In it, the following approximation appears:
[image]

What is this approximation? It seems elementary enough to have a name, but I do not believe that I have encountered it before. In fact, I can't even recall having seen this notation.

To be clear, I just want to know what the name of this trick is. Once I've got that, I'm happy to do any further reading myself.

Comment: It's called "composite midpoint (or rectangle) rule".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "[midpoint rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Midpoint_rule)" approximate Riemann sum/"method of Riemann summation". Note that they are using $dx$ to stand for a small real number (usually denoted $h$ or $\Delta x$), rather than something more calculus-y.